# Wordpress search term pagination broken

Tags: wordpress, pagination, permalinks

I'm having an issue with the pagination in search archives. For some reason whenever I try going to the next page the pagination gives me a 404.

It's a default `if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();` loop.

I don't know how, but I think the reason is because I'm getting redirected to a new page that get's generated somehow. Say I search for `stoff`. Instead of `/page/2/?s=stoff` it replaces it with `?attachment_id=550&s=stoff`.

**Here's what I've tried to do (with no different results)**

- Change the search query (attachment_id is the same here as well)
- Change pagination functions (pagenavi, get_next_posts_link, custom function)
- Replacing loop content with just a title
- removing header, sidebars, footer
- resetting post data
- Resetting permalinks (pretty)

You can test the pagination live [here](http://lines.screenpartner.no/?s=stoff) (dev location)

Any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT** -
*Added Pagination code currently used in search.php*

I don't think it should be a problem with the pagination, seeing that I've tried so many different ones, and this pagination still works in every other location at the site, but here it is:

```
// Numeric Page Navi (built into the theme by default)
function bones_page_navi() {
  global $wp_query;
  $bignum = 999999999;
  if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;
  echo '<nav class="pagination">';
  echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'         => str_replace( $bignum, '%#%', html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link($bignum) ) ),
    'format'       => '',
    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
    'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
    'type'         => 'list',
    'end_size'     => 3,
    'mid_size'     => 3
  ) );
  echo '</nav>';
} /* end page navi */
```

The function get's called after the `endwhile;`

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using for the pagination?

Comment: Sure, updating the answer with the code.

Comment: I think the problem is because you're not using pretty permalinks for your search page. Instead of doing http://lines.screenpartner.no/?s=stoff try for 
http://lines.screenpartner.no/search/stoff then you can do http://lines.screenpartner.no/search/stoff/page/2

Comment: How would I do that, I'm using pretty permalinks everywhere else on the site. Is there some kind of override or special conditions going on for the search query?

Comment: Thanks Elliot, I managed to work it out with a url rewrite function from http://bavotasan.com/2011/rewrite-search-result-url-for-wordpress/. It does seem weird though, that Wordpress doesn't do this automatically when enabling pretty permalinks..

Comment: Glad you got it working. It is strange default WP behavior. I think if you change the default search form action to point to something like: 
```<form action='<?=trailingslashit( get_site_url() ) . "search";?>'> ``` it will help as well.